# conflict between "action" attribute in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts

I have try to pass the action information like ( Save or Edit ) from my struts2 action class ( CommonAction.java ) to jsp file ( test.jsp ).

In action class, I used the below code to set action value.

```
request.setAttribute("action","Save");
```

When I try to get the action attribute in jsp file.

```
String actionValue = (String)request.getAttribute("action");
```

I am getting the action class instead of action value in my jsp file.

Below is the exception trace.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.actions.CommonAction cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:119)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
```

Is there any way to get action value without changing the attribute name ?

Comment: *Why* are you doing it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is provided by `StrutsRequestWrapper`. It overrides the `getAttribute()` method to support searching the OGNL value stack for attributes. You can disable the functionality by setting the following in your struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.disableRequestAttributeValueStackLookup" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, It working fine in Struts 2.3.15, previously I used 2.3.12.

Answer (score 0):

use `${requestScope.action}` in the your jsp page. if it return wrong value then declare a getter method (`public String getAction()`) in the your action and use previus EL code for get the result

```
action value: ${requestScope.action}
```